# I have problems with xcworkspace?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I passed my xcode file from my computer to a usb and open it on another computer my xcworkspace file, it does not show anything, only the files that are created at the time of implementing CocoaPods.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2106.png)

Something else that I notice, is that my podfile and podfile.lock files now appear this way

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfuPZ.png)

I'm using xcode 8 where I try to open my file, while the other computer has Xcode 7

I hope some one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem usually occurs when your project is trying to reference the wrong project folder.

#### #1 Click this in you Xcode Inspector:

[image: Click this..]

#### #2 Make sure the file path points to the correct project folder:

(Look on the right-hand side of the inspector and make sure the Page icon is selected)

[image: Fix this...]

Comment: Can you tell me why this happening, why the path do not change when i pass my project to my usb? because only this happen with this project, and i don't know if i need to change something in my project to work normally.